# Search to exclude html tags in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, search

I need a search query which will exclude text within HTML tags. For example, I need to search for a word called "spa" in my database. There are HTML tags in the database, so the result will contain `<span>` tags.

I need the search query to check only the words starting with the word "spa" but not within any HTML tag.

Please help.

Comment: Its not possible for me to use MySQL function as I don't have permission to create functions and global variables

Comment: How about using full-text search? (Provided the table is in myisam)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this using plain MySQL without functions. I think your best bet is to pre-process your text on insert, and create a new tokenized (and html-less) column to contain the processed text (or to store the processed text in a search engine like lucene).

Answer (score -1):

Regex are always really hard to use for HTML, cause there are many rules that apply to it.

You should consider using a HTML-Parser instead.